# how to find my SHARED_LIBRARY.lib with cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake file with shared library, built in another cmake in my project:

```
add_library(SHARED_LIBRARY SHARED ${SRCS}
```

I need to get the `.lib` file for another project who will link against it.

I tried:

1. `$<TARGET_FILE:target_name>` -> gives the .dll
2. `get_target_property(bla SHARED_LIBRARY LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)` -> gets `lib\windows.AMD64.Release\` while the actual lib is in `lib\windows.AMD64.Release\Release\SHARED_LIBRARY.lib`
3. same, using `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` -> empty
4. same, using `NAME` -> empty

I'm hoping to get a full path somehow, or a way to build it myself - something like `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` + `<build_type = Release>` + `<name = SHARED_LIBRARY>`

Comment: "I need to get the `.lib` file for another project who will link against it." - For link with a library you could just call `target_link_libraries` with the name of the **target** (SHARED_LIBRARY in your case). CMake will automatically transforms this name into the path.

Comment: If you meant that the project who needs to link - will call `target_link_libraries`, it's true, but not an option in my case, since I don't have that library installed on my system. It is built in a specific dir, and I want to pass its full path to the 2nd project, so it would be able to link against the full path - since the name of the lib is not enough (because it is not installed)

Comment: Recent CMake supports `$<TARGET_IMPORT_FILE:target_name>` [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_IMPORT_FILE). However, I am still not sure how do you intend to use it. If you want to use that expression in the 2nd project, then given project should have access to the **target**. But if the 2nd project has access to the target, it can simply use `target_link_libraries(2nd_project SHARED_LIBRARY)` for link with the library.

Comment: My project (current project) has access to the target - which may allow me to access `$<TARGET_IMPORT_FILE:target_name>` - however, I don't import it, but define it using `add_library` so I was under the impression that all `IMPORT` properties are irrelevant

Comment: You have checked the documentation under the reference, haven't you? The name `TARGET_IMPORT_FILE` has nothing common with the IMPORTED target. It is about "import file" - Windows concept of a `.lib` file which accompanies a `.dll` library.

Comment: Missed that... Will check it soon. Thanks!

Comment: @Tsyvarev didn't work for me... I `got Error evaluating generator expression: 
  $<TARGET_IMPORT_FILE:target_name>
 Expression did not evaluate to a known generator expression` - I'm trying to access it directly inside `add_custom_target(... COMMAND)`. Might be because `add_custom_target` is config-time? but if so, how can I fix that?

Comment: What is your CMake version? The generator expression `TARGET_IMPORT_FILE` appears only in CMake 3.27 (this is noted in the documentation). Make sure that your `cmake_minimum_required` has appropriate VERSION too.

Comment: Indeed, I have a too old version. Upgrading now

Comment: after upgrading to 3.28.3 and adding the `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.0)` it is still empty...